# Remove specific states of a country on Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, countries

I am trying to find a way to remove a few US states from the "State" dropdown in WooCommerce checkout page.

**List of states:**

1. Hawaii
2. Alaska
3. Armed Forces (AA)
4. Armed Forces (AE)
5. Armed Forces (AP)

**What I have been doing so far:**
I have been manually removing them as mentioned in this [link](https://wedevs.com/support/topic/remove-shipping-states/). But this is not a good way, as the changes get overwritten every time WooCommerce is updated.

**Alternative I found:**
On this link [WooCommerce restrict shipping to states based on category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930611/woocommerce-restrict-shipping-to-states-based-on-category), there's a way to **set** shipping states if specific condition is met. 
I am wondering if I can **unset** five states. This sounds more logical to me than *setting* 50 states. But unfortunately, I am not able to find anything useful.

Any ideas what could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is to remove them them using the dedicated filter hook `woocommerce_states` this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_us_states', 10, 1 );
function custom_us_states( $states ) {
    $non_allowed_us_states = array( 'AK', 'HI', 'AA', 'AE', 'AP'); 

    // Loop through your non allowed us states and remove them
    foreach( $non_allowed_us_states as $state_code ) {
        if( isset($states['US'][$state_code]) )
            unset( $states['US'][$state_code] );
    }
    return $states;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

> Then you can add some condition or make a custom settings page  like in the threads below:

- [Disable some states if specific products are in cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866551/disable-some-states-if-specific-products-are-in-cart-in-woocommerce/48867144#48867144)
- [US allowed States through Woocommerce custom setting page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486013/us-allowed-states-through-woocommerce-custom-setting-page/53494840#53494840)

Answer (score 2):

Best way of doing this would be using a filter, add this snippet in your themes functions.php

```
/**
 * Modify Woocommerce states array
 *
 * @param array $states, collection of all $states
 * @return array $states, modified array.
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', function( $states ){
    // Unset Hawaii
    unset( $states['US']['HI'] );

    return $states;
}, 999);
```

You can unset any states like this.

Comment: Some additional info, the prio 999 might not be needed but this ensures that you can also filter any data added by plugins.

If you're unsure what key values to use to unset the other states look them up in the sourcefile: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/i18n/states/US.php

Comment: Thank you, this works too. The only reason I accepted the other post as the answer is because it's complete with all state codes.